# JS - Filter an array of objects for duplicates of one property, and decide which object to keep based on another property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates, javascript-objects

Trying to filter an array of objects by eliminating objects that have a specific property that exists already in another object (duplicate). The decision which object to remove should be based on another property.

Example:
For an array of objects, that might look like this, the goal would be to filter all "user" duplicates and keep the one with the oldest "date" property.

```
const arr = [
    {user: 'Alex', date: '1540801929945'},
    {user: 'Bill', date: '1640801929946'},
    {user: 'Carl', date: '1740801929947'},
    {user: 'Alex', date: '1840801929948'},
]
```

Expected outcome:

```
filteredArr = [
    {user: 'Alex', date: '1540801929945'},
    {user: 'Bill', date: '1640801929946'},
    {user: 'Carl', date: '1740801929947'},
]
```

I managed the basic filtering that works for keeping only unique objects.

```
const filteredArr = arr.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.user === o.user) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);
```

Though I can't figure out, what to do so that in the case of a duplicate the "oldest" object stays and the latest get removed.
Thanks so much for your help! Really appreciated.

Comment: is your data sorted by `date`?

Comment: No unfortunately not. The objects are in real usecase much bigger and sorted in different ways depending on where used...

Comment: do you habe only the given two properties or more? do you want to keep the objects?

Comment: Yes, there are more properties. Don't plan to keep the objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reduce the array to an object with the `user` as the key. If a user is not in `unique` object, or if it's date is "older" than the what that is, add it to the object. Convert the object to array with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

**Note:** since you the dates are string, convert them to a number while comparing (I use the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())).

```js
const array = [{ user: 'Alex', date: '1540801929945' }, { user: 'Bill', date: '1640801929946' }, { user: 'Carl', date: '1740801929947' }, { user: 'Alex', date: '1840801929948' }];


const filteredArray = Object.values(array.reduce((unique, o) => {
  if(!unique[o.user] || +o.date > +unique[o.user].date) unique[o.user] = o;
  
  return unique;
}, {}));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: I guess it's  (...) `+o.date < +unique[o.user].date)` (...) -- but otherwise it seems to work. Thanks so much for helping out!

Comment: @YvonC - I'm not sure what your comment refers to. Your objects include `date`, and not `dateofpost`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and a single loop approach

```js
var array = [{ user: 'Alex', date: '1540801929945' }, { user: 'Bill', date: '1640801929946' }, { user: 'Carl', date: '1740801929947' }, { user: 'Alex', date: '1840801929948' }],
    filtered = Array.from(array
        .reduce((m, o) => !m.has(o.user) || m.get(o.user).data > o.date
            ? m.set(o.user, o)
            : m, new Map)
       .values());
      
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For sorted data (take sorting in advance by `date`), you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for filtering.

```js
var array = [{ user: 'Alex', date: '1540801929945' }, { user: 'Bill', date: '1640801929946' }, { user: 'Carl', date: '1740801929947' }, { user: 'Alex', date: '1840801929948' }],
    filtered = array
        .sort(({ date: a }, { date: b }) => a - b)
        .filter((s => ({ user }) => !s.has(user) && s.add(user))(new Set));
      
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For an `O(N)` solution, `reduce` into an object indexed by `user`, whose values are `date`s - on each iteration, if something at that `user` already exists, keep only the lowest `date`. Then, iterate over the object's `entries` to turn it back into an array:

```js
const arr = [
    {user: 'Alex', date: '1540801929945'},
    {user: 'Bill', date: '1640801929946'},
    {user: 'Carl', date: '1740801929947'},
    {user: 'Alex', date: '1840801929948'},
    {user: 'Carl', date: '1340801929947'},
];

const arrByUser = arr.reduce((a, { user, date }) => {
  if (!a[user]) a[user] = date;
  else if (a[user].localeCompare(date) === 1) a[user] = date;
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.entries(arrByUser)
  .map(([user, date]) => ({ user, date }));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you actually need to know the index of the non-unique element (Object with name "Alex" in your case) and then compare their dates, saving the older one.

Array.prototype.find wil lnot do you mouch good in this case.
However, Array.prototype.find can be of help since it takes a callback which returns a boolean( just like 'some') BUT it returns the index of the element matched by your callback, or undefined if no such element is found.

Give it a try, it cant hurt :)